# Test Failure Message in mockito : Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

Tags: junit, mockito

I am testing a Restful endpoint in my JUnit and getting an exception as below in the 
list which is present as an argument inside the save method,

```
**"Argument(s) are different! Wanted:"** 
save(
"121",
[com.domain.PP@6809cf9d, 
com.domain.PP@5925d603]
);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
save(
"121",
[com.domain.PP@5b6e23fd,  
com.domain.PP@1791fe40]
 );
```

When I debugged the code, the code broke at the **verify** line below and threw the 
above exception. Looks like the arguments inside the "testpPList" within the save 
method is different. I dont know how it becomes different as I construct them in my 
JUNit properly and then RestFul URL is invoked.

Requesting your valuable inputs. Thanks.

Code:

```
@Test
public void testSelected() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(put("/endpointURL")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(testObject)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    verify(programServiceMock, times(1)).save(id, testpPList);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(programServiceMock);
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpointURL", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody void uPP(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody List<PPView> pPViews) {
    // Code to construct the list which is passed into the save method below
    save(id, pPList);
}
```

Answer (score 56):

Implementing the `Object#equals(Object)` can solve it by the equality comparison. Nonetheless, sometimes the object you are validating cannot be changed or its `equals` function can not be implemented. For such cases, it's recommended using `org.mockito.Matchers#refEq(T value, String... excludeFields)`. So you may use something like:

```
verify(programServiceMock, times(1)).save(id, refEq(testpPList));
```

Just wrapping the argument with `refEq` solves the problem.

Comment: Awesome answer !! Worked for me. Syntax as follows:

verify(serviceName).methodCall(refEq(passedParameter));

Comment: I tried, but in my case it says:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.refEq(transactionToAdd) must not be null`

Comment: @iDemigod it seems that your variable `transactionToAdd` is null and thats why it fails for you.

Comment: @EliuX , yeah but it's because of Kotlin/Java relations on nullable objects (resolved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489612/3569545)

Comment: refEq (ref is shortcut from "reflection", not "reference" in that case) worked for me.
But with 2 argument methods I had to also wrap the second argument - In my case i used eq.
So in solution provided by EliuX - something like:
verify(programServiceMock, times(1)).save(eq(id), refEq(testpPList));

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you implement the `equals` method in `com.domain.PP`.

**[Edit]**

The reasoning for this conclusion is that your failed test message states that it expects this list of `PP`

```
[com.domain.PP@6809cf9d, com.domain.PP@5925d603]
```

but it's getting this list of PP

```
[com.domain.PP@5b6e23fd, com.domain.PP@1791fe40]
```

The hex values after the `@` symbol for each `PP` object is their hash codes. Because they are different, then it shows that they belong to different objects. So the default implementation of equals will say they're not equal, which is what `verify()` uses.

It's good practice to also implement [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) whenever you implement [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)): According to the definition of hashCode, two objects that are equal MUST have equal hashCodes. This ensures that objects like HashMap can use hashCode inequality as a shortcut for object inequality (here, placing objects with different hashCodes in different buckets).

Comment: That's a great explanation to the problem. But this requires to change the java code in order to run successful JUnit test. Instead of implementing equals method in java class is there any other elegant solution?