# Android Mockito.verify says Argument(s) are different! with printing same content

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito

**The situation**

I have an interface of a `Tracker` which has this method:

```
fun trackEvent(event: String, args: Bundle? = null)
```

I want to verify, that this method is called with a specific `event`.
Internally object that being tested call this method with `Bundle` object.
All the events are specified as

```
companion object {
        const val EVENT = "EVENT"
}
```

**The problem**

The test fails with this verification:

```
Mockito.verify(tracker).trackEvent(Tracker.EVENT)
```

with message:

*Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
tracker.trackEvent("EVENT", null);
...*

*Actual invocation has different arguments:
tracker.trackEvent("EVENT", null);
...*

There are many solutions, which are using 
`Mockito.eq()`, `Mockito.refEq()`, `ArgumentMatchers`, `Captures`, etc. None of them worked for me, giving the same or `NullPointerException`

Comment: Out of interest, does replacing the test with `Mockito.verify(tracker).trackEvent(eq("EVENT"))` pass? Not proposing that as an answer, just curious.

Comment: It gives `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.eq(Tracker.EVENT) must not be null` exception.

Comment: Even if you use the String `"EVENT"` in quotes and not the constant?

Comment: Also any particular reason as to why `EVENT` is declared inside the `companion object` and not at top level?

Comment: What happens if you `verify(tracker).trackEvent(Tracker.EVENT, null)` explicitly?

Comment: Whether explicitly as `String` or with second parameter as `null`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who will face same problem, the solution is that you need to add
`testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"` in your `build.gradle` file. More info, here
https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin.

The thing is that in `Java` all classes are nullable by default, unlike `Kotlin`. While mockito is designed to be used with `Java`, the library from above adds support using Mockito with `Kotlin`.

So, the solution to this particular test

```
Mockito.verify(tracker).trackEvent(Tracker.EVENT)
```

is

```
Mockito.verify(tracker).trackEvent(eq(Tracker.ADD_TRANSACTION), any())
```

where `eq()` and `any()` are functions of `com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin`.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38722935/3569545